# Get Min and Max label in from the array loop

Tags: c

I am trying to find minimum and maximum values from the file. When the program reads the file, every value goes into `numbers[]` array. My goal is to display some information regarding each value in the array, here is the expected output:

[image]

My program works fine, however I have a problem to display Max and Min labels in my `for loop`. Here my code:

```
typedef struct Points {
  int min;
  int max;
} Point;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  returnNumbersArray("numbers.txt");

  // Display output
  printf("Sr.\t\tNumber\t\tPrime\t\tOdd/Even\t\tMin/Max\n");

  for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%s\n", i + 1,
      numbers[i],
      (isPrime(numbers[i]) ? "Yes":"No"),
      (isOddOrEven(numbers[i]) ? "Odd":"Even"));
  }


  // Define Min and Max values
  getMinMax(numbers);
  printf("%d, %d", point.max, point.min);

  return 0;
}

// Return min and max value from the array.
Point getMinMax(int array[]) {
  point.max = point.min = array[0];
  for (int i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    if (array[i] > point.max) {
      point.max = array[i];
    }
    if (array[i] < point.min) {
      point.min = array[i];
    }
  }
  return point;
}
```

`getMinMax(int array[])` works and I do get Min and Max values but I want to put a proper label inside my `for loop` in the `main` method and use the same approach as `isPrime(numbers[i]) ? "Yes":"No"`. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong or give an advice to solve this problem?

My current output:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Point minmax = getMinMax(numbers);
for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
    printf("%d\t\t%d\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%s\t\t\t%s\n",
        i + 1,
        numbers[i],
        (isPrime(numbers[i]) ? "Yes" : "No"),
        (isOddOrEven(numbers[i]) ? "Odd" : "Even"),
        (numbers[i] == minmax.max ? "Max" : (numbers[i] == minmax.min ? "Min" : ""))
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't know that I can do it this way.